# Returning array from complex documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get an array of id's into an array of strings and not objects.

Folowing query works:

```
SELECT * FROM c.id
```

Returns:

```
[
    "92226d610a1047ecb207c98f845bde14",
    "3936d9172f8c4bfd891a91457935f1ac",
    "ab466a79f1b44fc99c0f2fcefbec0aa2",
    "0d5254279e02430ba8f09afbbd6f2259",
    "b768a932ac9042f096557eea3ad5bc4e",
    "6917916a41724249a1ae85963f46d58d",
    "593ff8f0ceab4b2c8279d77b270307e4"]
```

However when I add a where clause it fails:

```
SELECT * FROM c.id where c.vesselId="6c0f3e571b0f4e3bb96f82e6b08d8d36"
```

What is the best approach to get an array with a where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct value` clause to derive ids as array.

```
select distinct value c.id from c where c.vesselId ='6c0f3e571b0f4e3bb96f82e6b08d8d36'
```